# What is the term for the overlapping panel of this type of double-breasted uniform jacket?

Tags: terminology

I'm looking for the term of art in suit- and jacket-making for a specific design element that appears on some types of military, especially navy, uniform jackets, like these ones (left to right: a British Admiralty ceremonial day dress uniform, the cover of an Honor Harrington novel, cosplay of same), which are double-breasted, have no lapels, and which fasten up to the collar:

[image]
[image]
[image]

*(click for larger images)*

Is there a specific term for the large, rectangular type of extremely overlapping front panel that appears in these double-breasted jackets? Failing that, is there a name for this lapel-free style of double-breasted jacket?

I've found *front panel* in the “Double-Breasted” entry in an great [glossary of suit & tailoring terms](https://bespokeunit.com/suits/glossary/#letter_D), but that term merely describes the two front pieces of any garment. More specific is [*placket*](https://www.office-dress-shirts.com/shirt_placket.html), but this is still just a general term for the overlap of fabric where clothes are fastened.

I had expected to find a specific term of art for this element within this style of jacket, since as a discipline suit tailoring has myriad terms for stylistic variations (such as how a shoulder can be *rope*, *pagoda*, and *natural*), but I'm failing to find anything for the variations of double-breasted designs, let alone for the elements of this specific variation.

This is for a novel where, for better or worse, the details of uniforms are narratively important, and using specific vocabulary is part of achieving the overall voice I'm aiming for.

Is *placket* the best term that exists for this design element? Does the overall style have no name?

---

*Image sources: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Adrian_johns1.jpg), [TVTropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/HonorHarrington), and [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/alyjack/7936970662), respectively.*

Comment: My immediate thought was "lappet"; but that seems to be a smaller thing.

Comment: I always assumed that jackets started out like this and that when the full front panels were not buttoned all they way up they folded them back to let. In some air forming the lapel.  Then that evolved into a stylized version that was permanently folded back and reduced in size. So  that part ***is*** the lapel, it’s just not folded back.

Comment: @Jim I believe you’re right about the evolution! There is still a vestigial button hole in the left lapel of a suit because suits originally buttoned all the way against weather. However, the term *lapel* is a diminutive; as far as I can tell it only applied to the little folded back triangles once they became a deliberate design feature. I suppose I could back-form it to *lap (of the jacket)*, but I’d rather not if I’m just missing the existing term. :)

Comment: Overlapping panel or front flap would get the point across without calling undue attention.

Comment: @YosefBaskin If those are correct, that would work, but avoiding undue attention is contrary to my purpose. Attention to detail is part of the intended voice. The danger is appearing sloppy in my references to things a portion of my audience will already be familiar with. For example, if writing a  novel about WW2 pilots, a reference to parts of the plane should either use correct terms, or be avoided entirely. If the story requires such details be included though, then correct terminology is the only option. Detailed descriptions of uniforms are part of the kind of space opera I'm writing.